# Export the legend into its 100% size using Print Composer

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, legend

I am trying to export the legend into an image using Print Composer into its 100% size as it is in the composer window. To be sure it is the intended size I want, I clicked **Zoom to 100%**:

[image: Zoom to 100%]

But upon clicking **Export as Image**, I am forced to specify the image width and resolution, and there is no option for exporting into the 100% legend size as viewed in the Composer window:

[image: Image export options]

Clicking **Crop to Content** doesn't help as I need to specify the resolution in dpi, which I need to painstakingly readjust just to get the 100% size. I also tried using 100 dpi as the export resolution but the resulting image is not its full size.

I had thought there should be a simpler solution than manually readjusting the dpi, but I don't know how. How can I export the legend into its 100% size?

Comment: Why only the legend? Maybe it would be helpful to set a blank map in the background and export that "map" with the legend included? After done that, you could change (in gimp/inkscape etc.)  the background color (white maybe) to transparent if that is your origin intend.

Comment: It appears I have no choice but to use Export as SVG instead of Export as Image to preserve the quality, then from there use Inkscape to export it into a png. The actual size of the legend was not modified upon export.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need only the legend in high resolution.
If so make a new Print Composer and add only the Legend into it [image]
Know go to Composition and click on the Resize Page [image]
Choose the resolution you need and save it as any other Print Composer export map[image]
Know you will have an image at the size of the Legend as it was in the Print Composer [image]

Comment: Thanks, but the export resolution options in the 3rd picture you have posted makes it problematic. The resulting export in the fourth picture had its resolution increased. What I need is the actual size of the legend (like it is in the second picture) in the Print Composer, and I have no idea what the equivalent dpi is for the 100% size. I tried using 100 dpi and 96 dpi, but some of the legend text were rendered too close/connected with each other (like 'ci' appearing as 'a').

Comment: It's not very elegant, but you allays can  make a print screen and crop the image in PowerPoint or some other software.